# Android Mupdf : PDF viewer silenty crashed due to low memory after 13 pages

Tags: android, crash, mupdf, low-memory

I am trying opened a large pdf file (10MB) which has high resolution images embedded on it with internal links,It seems to be working fine up to 13 pages when I continuous clicked the next page button. After 13 pages the application silently restart with list of all magazines files.

I am facing the issue with both 1.0 and 1.1 version.

Source for apk : http://code.google.com/p/mupdf/downloads/list

Tested on      : Sony Ericsson XPERIA

```
model      : X10i
```

sdk version    : 2.3.3

Please check the log cat content attached below.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank You.

```
08-20 13:58:52.670: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:58:52.670: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:58:52.670: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:58:52.670: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:58:53.370: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendered
08-20 13:58:53.370: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 2...
08-20 13:58:54.460: D/dalvikvm(10800): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1233K, 56% free 3165K/7047K, external 6492K/6609K, paused 2ms+7ms
08-20 13:58:54.660: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 3...
08-20 13:58:54.670: E/libmupdf(10800): PageWidth=1191
08-20 13:58:54.670: E/libmupdf(10800): PageHeight=1588
08-20 13:58:54.710: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:58:54.710: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:58:54.710: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:58:54.710: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:58:58.390: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendered
08-20 13:58:58.390: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 3...
08-20 13:58:58.390: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 4...
08-20 13:58:58.400: E/libmupdf(10800): PageWidth=1191
08-20 13:58:58.400: E/libmupdf(10800): PageHeight=1588
08-20 13:58:58.410: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:58:58.410: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:58:58.410: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:58:58.410: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:59:01.670: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendered
08-20 13:59:01.670: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 4...
08-20 13:59:01.670: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 5...
08-20 13:59:01.710: E/libmupdf(10800): PageWidth=1191
08-20 13:59:01.710: E/libmupdf(10800): PageHeight=1588
08-20 13:59:01.730: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:59:01.730: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:59:01.730: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:59:01.730: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:59:05.080: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendered
08-20 13:59:05.080: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 5...
08-20 13:59:05.080: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 6...
08-20 13:59:05.120: E/libmupdf(10800): PageWidth=1191
08-20 13:59:05.120: E/libmupdf(10800): PageHeight=1588
08-20 13:59:05.130: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:59:05.130: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:59:05.130: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:59:05.130: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:59:08.260: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendered
08-20 13:59:08.260: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 6...
08-20 13:59:08.260: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 7...
08-20 13:59:08.270: E/libmupdf(10800): PageWidth=1191
08-20 13:59:08.270: E/libmupdf(10800): PageHeight=1588
08-20 13:59:08.280: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:59:08.280: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:59:08.280: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:59:08.280: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:59:11.350: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendered
08-20 13:59:11.350: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 7...
08-20 13:59:11.350: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 8...
08-20 13:59:11.350: E/libmupdf(10800): PageWidth=1191
08-20 13:59:11.350: E/libmupdf(10800): PageHeight=1588
08-20 13:59:11.370: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:59:11.370: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:59:11.370: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:59:11.370: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:59:12.050: D/dalvikvm(10800): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1875K, 59% free 3239K/7751K, external 6492K/6609K, paused 2ms+8ms
08-20 13:59:14.350: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendered
08-20 13:59:14.350: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 8...
08-20 13:59:14.350: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 9...
08-20 13:59:14.390: E/libmupdf(10800): PageWidth=1191
08-20 13:59:14.390: E/libmupdf(10800): PageHeight=1588
08-20 13:59:14.390: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:59:14.390: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:59:14.390: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:59:14.390: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:59:17.500: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendered
08-20 13:59:17.500: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 9...
08-20 13:59:17.510: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 10...
08-20 13:59:17.550: E/libmupdf(10800): PageWidth=1191
08-20 13:59:17.550: E/libmupdf(10800): PageHeight=1588
08-20 13:59:17.550: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:59:17.550: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:59:17.550: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:59:17.550: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:59:22.690: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendered
08-20 13:59:22.830: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 10...
08-20 13:59:22.830: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 11...
08-20 13:59:22.850: E/libmupdf(10800): PageWidth=1191
08-20 13:59:22.850: E/libmupdf(10800): PageHeight=1588
08-20 13:59:22.890: I/ActivityManager(1231): Start proc com.sonyericsson.eventstream.telephonyplugin for service com.sonyericsson.eventstream.telephonyplugin/.TelephonyPluginService: pid=11006 uid=10058 gids={}
08-20 13:59:22.910: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:59:22.910: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:59:22.910: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:59:22.910: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:59:24.490: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.sonyericsson.pccompanion (pid 10834) has died.
08-20 13:59:25.110: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.sonyericsson.android.support (pid 10850) has died.
08-20 13:59:25.970: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process android.process.acore (pid 10914) has died.
08-20 13:59:27.460: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendered
08-20 13:59:27.460: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 11...
08-20 13:59:27.460: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 12...
08-20 13:59:27.490: E/libmupdf(10800): PageWidth=1191
08-20 13:59:27.490: E/libmupdf(10800): PageHeight=1588
08-20 13:59:27.510: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:59:27.510: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:59:27.510: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:59:27.510: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:59:30.990: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendered
08-20 13:59:30.990: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 12...
08-20 13:59:30.990: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 13...
08-20 13:59:31.010: E/libmupdf(10800): PageWidth=1191
08-20 13:59:31.010: E/libmupdf(10800): PageHeight=1588
08-20 13:59:31.040: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:59:31.040: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:59:31.040: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:59:31.040: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:59:32.140: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.sonyericsson.customization (pid 10860) has died.
08-20 13:59:32.140: I/ActivityManager(1231): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-20 13:59:33.200: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.sonyericsson.eventstream.telephonyplugin (pid 11006) has died.
08-20 13:59:33.200: W/ActivityManager(1231): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.eventstream.telephonyplugin/.TelephonyPluginService in 705872ms
08-20 13:59:33.200: I/ActivityManager(1231): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-20 13:59:33.660: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.sonyericsson.devicemonitor (pid 10951) has died.
08-20 13:59:33.660: W/ActivityManager(1231): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.devicemonitor/.DeviceMonitorService in 5000ms
08-20 13:59:33.660: I/ActivityManager(1231): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-20 13:59:34.310: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.sonyericsson.sync.service (pid 10876) has died.
08-20 13:59:34.310: W/ActivityManager(1231): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.sync.service/sync.service.SemcRepeatingSyncManagerService in 34213ms
08-20 13:59:34.310: I/ActivityManager(1231): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-20 13:59:34.960: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendered
08-20 13:59:34.960: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 13...
08-20 13:59:34.960: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 14...
08-20 13:59:34.970: E/libmupdf(10800): PageWidth=1191
08-20 13:59:34.970: E/libmupdf(10800): PageHeight=1588
08-20 13:59:35.010: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:59:35.010: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:59:35.010: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:59:35.010: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:59:35.160: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.sonyericsson.crashmonitor (pid 10986) has died.
08-20 13:59:35.170: W/ActivityManager(1231): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.crashmonitor/.CrashMonitorService in 579664ms
08-20 13:59:35.170: I/ActivityManager(1231): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-20 13:59:35.920: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.sonyericsson.android.bootinfo:remote (pid 10995) has died.
08-20 13:59:35.920: I/ActivityManager(1231): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-20 13:59:36.610: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.sonyericsson.secureclockservice (pid 10808) has died.
08-20 13:59:36.610: W/ActivityManager(1231): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.secureclockservice/.SecureClockEventListenerService in 41912ms
08-20 13:59:36.610: W/ActivityManager(1231): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.secureclockservice/.SecureClockStartupService in 51912ms
08-20 13:59:36.610: I/ActivityManager(1231): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-20 13:59:37.210: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.sonyericsson.eventstream.calllogplugin (pid 10963) has died.
08-20 13:59:37.210: W/ActivityManager(1231): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.eventstream.calllogplugin/.CallLogPluginService in 61313ms
08-20 13:59:37.210: I/ActivityManager(1231): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-20 13:59:38.370: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendered
08-20 13:59:38.370: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 14...
08-20 13:59:38.370: E/libmupdf(10800): Goto page 15...
08-20 13:59:38.420: E/libmupdf(10800): PageWidth=1191
08-20 13:59:38.420: E/libmupdf(10800): PageHeight=1588
08-20 13:59:38.430: I/libmupdf(10800): In native method
08-20 13:59:38.430: I/libmupdf(10800): Checking format
08-20 13:59:38.430: I/libmupdf(10800): locking pixels
08-20 13:59:38.430: E/libmupdf(10800): Rendering page=480x640 patch=[0,0,480,640]
08-20 13:59:38.600: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp (pid 10943) has died.
08-20 13:59:38.600: W/ActivityManager(1231): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp/.glue.InputMethodServiceGlue in 69922ms
08-20 13:59:38.600: I/ActivityManager(1231): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231): Session failed to close due to remote exception
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231): android.os.DeadObjectException
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:346)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSession(InputMethodManagerService.java:896)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:907)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:924)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1069)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1083)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:549)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231): Session failed to close due to remote exception
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231): android.os.DeadObjectException
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:346)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSession(InputMethodManagerService.java:896)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:911)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:924)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1069)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1083)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-20 13:59:38.630: W/InputManagerService(1231):    at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:549)
08-20 13:59:38.690: I/ActivityManager(1231): Start proc com.sonyericsson.devicemonitor for service com.sonyericsson.devicemonitor/.DeviceMonitorService: pid=11015 uid=10010 gids={3003, 3002, 1007}
08-20 13:59:39.230: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.sonyericsson.devicemonitor (pid 11015) has died.
08-20 13:59:39.230: W/ActivityManager(1231): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sonyericsson.devicemonitor/.DeviceMonitorService in 79293ms
08-20 13:59:39.230: I/ActivityManager(1231): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-20 13:59:39.700: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.google.process.gapps (pid 10888) has died.
08-20 13:59:39.700: W/ActivityManager(1231): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gsf/.gtalkservice.service.GTalkService in 5000ms
08-20 13:59:39.700: W/ActivityManager(1231): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.location/.NetworkLocationService in 88820ms
08-20 13:59:39.700: I/ActivityManager(1231): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-20 13:59:40.100: D/GeocoderProxy(1231): onServiceDisconnected ComponentInfo{com.google.android.location/com.google.android.location.NetworkLocationService}
08-20 13:59:40.100: D/LocationProviderProxy(1231): LocationProviderProxy.onServiceDisconnected ComponentInfo{com.google.android.location/com.google.android.location.NetworkLocationService}
08-20 13:59:40.440: D/dalvikvm(10800): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1939K, 59% free 3249K/7815K, external 6492K/6609K, paused 3ms+12ms
08-20 13:59:42.190: I/ActivityManager(1231): Process com.artifex.mupdf (pid 10800) has died.
08-20 13:59:42.190: I/WindowManager(1231): WIN DEATH: Window{4091b3f0 com.artifex.mupdf/com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFActivity paused=false}
08-20 13:59:42.190: E/InputDispatcher(1231): channel '409046a0 com.artifex.mupdf/com.artifex.mupdf.ChoosePDFActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-20 13:59:42.190: E/InputDispatcher(1231): channel '409046a0 com.artifex.mupdf/com.artifex.mupdf.ChoosePDFActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-20 13:59:42.210: I/WindowManager(1231): WIN DEATH: Window{409046a0 com.artifex.mupdf/com.artifex.mupdf.ChoosePDFActivity paused=false}
08-20 13:59:42.210: E/InputDispatcher(1231): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=190, events=0x8
08-20 13:59:42.230: I/ActivityManager(1231): Start proc com.artifex.mupdf for activity com.artifex.mupdf/.ChoosePDFActivity: pid=11024 uid=10146 gids={}
08-20 13:59:42.230: I/ActivityManager(1231): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-20 13:59:42.710: W/InputManagerService(1231): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 10800 uid 10146
08-20 13:59:42.740: I/ActivityManager(1231): Displayed com.artifex.mupdf/.ChoosePDFActivity: +521ms
08-20 13:59:44.720: I/ActivityManager(1231): Start proc com.google.process.gapps for service com.google.android.gsf/.gtalkservice.service.GTalkService: pid=11032 uid=10022 gids={3003, 1015, 2001, 1007}
08-20 13:59:44.790: I/ActivityThread(11032): Pub com.google.settings: com.google.android.gsf.settings.GoogleSettingsProvider
08-20 13:59:44.811: I/ActivityThread(11032): Pub subscribedfeeds: com.google.android.gsf.subscribedfeeds.SubscribedFeedsProvider
08-20 13:59:44.940: I/ActivityThread(11032): Pub com.google.android.gsf.gservices: com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider
08-20 13:59:44.940: I/GservicesProvider(11032): Gservices pushing to system: true; secure: true
08-20 13:59:44.940: I/ActivityThread(11032): Pub com.google.android.providers.talk: com.google.android.gsf.talk.TalkProvider
08-20 13:59:45.160: D/SyncManager(1231): setSyncAutomatically: , provider subscribedfeeds -> true
08-20 13:59:45.160: D/SyncManager(1231): setSyncAutomatically: already set to true, doing nothing
08-20 13:59:45.170: D/GTalkService(11032): lost connectivity, notify
08-20 13:59:45.300: D/GTalkService(11032): [GTalkConnection.26] init: initialized presence to AVAILABLE(x) pmuc-v1
08-20 13:59:45.300: D/GTalkService(11032): [GTalkConnection.26] ensurePresenceHandlerLoginState: call RosterListenerImpl.onLoggedIn
08-20 13:59:45.300: D/GTalkService(11032): [RosterListenerImpl] onLoggedIn
08-20 13:59:45.430: I/ActivityManager(1231): Start proc android.process.acore for content provider com.android.providers.contacts/.SemcContactsProvider2: pid=11058 uid=10012 gids={3003}
08-20 13:59:45.470: D/dalvikvm(1145): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 53% free 2556K/5379K, external 1685K/2133K, paused 38ms
08-20 13:59:45.510: D/GTalkService(11032): [GTalkImSession] login: kbvk527@gmail.com, hostConn.connState = RECONNECTION_SCHEDULED, hostConn.error=NO ERROR
08-20 13:59:45.510: D/GTalkService(11032): [GTalkConnection.26] connect: network unavailable, set state=PENDING, err=NO_NETWORK
08-20 13:59:45.510: D/GTalkService(11032): [RosterListenerImpl] onLoggedIn
08-20 13:59:45.520: D/dalvikvm(1145): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 53% free 2556K/5379K, external 1685K/2133K, paused 46ms
08-20 13:59:45.520: I/ActivityThread(11058): Pub contacts;com.android.contacts: com.android.providers.contacts.SemcContactsProvider2
08-20 13:59:45.580: D/dalvikvm(1145): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 53% free 2556K/5379K, external 1685K/2133K, paused 66ms
08-20 13:59:45.870: I/ActivityThread(11058): Pub user_dictionary: com.android.providers.userdictionary.UserDictionaryProvider
08-20 13:59:45.880: I/ActivityThread(11058): Pub call_log: com.android.providers.contacts.SemcCallLogProvider
08-20 13:59:45.880: I/ActivityThread(11058): Pub com.android.social: com.android.providers.contacts.SocialProvider
08-20 13:59:45.880: I/ActivityThread(11058): Pub applications: com.android.providers.applications.ApplicationsProvider
08-20 13:59:45.990: D/GTalkService(11032): [GTalkConnection.24] EVENT_REQUEST_ROSTER: not connected
08-20 13:59:50.120: D/skia(1299): purging 8K from font cache [1 entries]
08-20 13:59:50.150: D/dalvikvm(1299): GC_EXPLICIT freed 21K, 56% free 2870K/6407K, external 2586K/3164K, paused 30ms
08-20 13:59:55.120: D/skia(1231): purging 23K from font cache [3 entries]
08-20 13:59:55.210: D/dalvikvm(1231): GC_EXPLICIT freed 442K, 47% free 6830K/12743K, external 4080K/5095K, paused 93ms
08-20 13:59:58.540: I/ActivityManager(1231): Start proc com.sonyericsson.setupwizard for service com.sonyericsson.setupwizard/.simcard.SimService: pid=11067 uid=10092 gids={3003, 1015}
08-20 14:00:05.060: D/dalvikvm(1335): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 51% free 3032K/6151K, external 1685K/2133K, paused 34ms
08-20 14:00:08.560: I/ActivityManager(1231): Start proc com.sonyericsson.sync.service for service com.sonyericsson.sync.service/sync.service.SemcRepeatingSyncManagerService: pid=11076 uid=10043 gids={3003}
08-20 14:00:08.730: I/ActivityThread(11076): Pub com.sonyericsson.syncml.Account: sync.service.provider.SonyEricssonAccountProvider
08-20 14:00:08.780: D/SYNCML/APPLICATION(11076): Creating wake-lock for BroadcastReceivers
08-20 14:00:08.780: D/SYNCML/PROVIDER(11076): onAccountsUpdated([Account {name=Phone contacts, type=com.sonyericsson.localcontacts}, Account {name=kbvk527@gmail.com, type=com.google}, Account {name=kbvk527@gmail.com, type=com.facebook.auth.login}, Account {name=kbvk527@gmail.com, type=com.sonyericsson.facebook.account}])
08-20 14:00:08.810: D/SYNCML/PROVIDER(11076): Starting static initialization of registry
08-20 14:00:08.810: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading uri from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/versit.rpc.contacts.ContactsDataService}
08-20 14:00:08.810: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading authority from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/versit.rpc.contacts.ContactsDataService}
08-20 14:00:08.810: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading name from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/versit.rpc.contacts.ContactsDataService}
08-20 14:00:08.810: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading description from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/versit.rpc.contacts.ContactsDataService}
08-20 14:00:08.810: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading mime-type from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/versit.rpc.contacts.ContactsDataService}
08-20 14:00:08.820: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading uri from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/versit.rpc.bookmarks.BookmarksDataService}
08-20 14:00:08.820: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading authority from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/versit.rpc.bookmarks.BookmarksDataService}
08-20 14:00:08.820: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading name from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/versit.rpc.bookmarks.BookmarksDataService}
08-20 14:00:08.820: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading description from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/versit.rpc.bookmarks.BookmarksDataService}
08-20 14:00:08.820: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading mime-type from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/versit.rpc.bookmarks.BookmarksDataService}
08-20 14:00:08.820: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading uri from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/sync.service.SEMCCalendar2DataService}
08-20 14:00:08.820: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading authority from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/sync.service.SEMCCalendar2DataService}
08-20 14:00:08.820: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading name from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/sync.service.SEMCCalendar2DataService}
08-20 14:00:08.820: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading description from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/sync.service.SEMCCalendar2DataService}
08-20 14:00:08.820: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Reading mime-type from ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.sync.service/sync.service.SEMCCalendar2DataService}
08-20 14:00:08.830: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Row already exists, skipping update
08-20 14:00:08.830: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Row already exists, skipping update
08-20 14:00:08.840: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Row already exists, skipping update
08-20 14:00:08.840: D/SYNCML/MAINTENANCE(11076): Found rows, deleting all missing rows in registry
08-20 14:00:08.880: I/ActivityManager(1231): Start proc com.sonyericsson.customization for content provider com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/.CustomizationProvider: pid=11086 uid=10083 gids={}
08-20 14:00:08.900: I/ActivityThread(11086): Pub com.sonyericsson.provider.useragent: com.sonyericsson.provider.useragent.UserAgentProvider
08-20 14:00:08.910: D/ActivityThread(11086): Loading provider com.sonyericsson.provider.customization: com.sonyericsson.provider.customization.CustomizationProvider
08-20 14:00:08.920: I/CustomizationProvider(11086): No configuration file: /system/etc/customization/settings/com/sonyericsson/provider/useragent/custom_settings.xml
08-20 14:00:08.920: W/UserAgentProvider(11086): onCreatejava.io.FileNotFoundException
08-20 14:00:08.920: I/ActivityThread(11086): Pub com.sonyericsson.provider.customization: com.sonyericsson.provider.customization.CustomizationProvider
08-20 14:00:08.920: I/CustomizationProvider(11086): No configuration file: /system/etc/customization/settings/com/sonyericsson/sync/service/customization/custom_settings.xml
08-20 14:00:08.920: W/SyncAccountCustomization(11076): Unable to find customization file
08-20 14:00:09.930: W/SyncAccountCustomization(11076): Stop CustomizationService
08-20 14:00:18.540: I/ActivityManager(1231): Start proc com.sonyericsson.secureclockservice for service com.sonyericsson.secureclockservice/.SecureClockEventListenerService: pid=11096 uid=10085 gids={3003}
08-20 14:00:18.570: I/SecureClock(11096): The listener for network connectivity is set up
08-20 14:00:18.570: I/SecureClock(11096): Generate an initial secure clock value.
08-20 14:00:18.570: I/SecureClock(11096): Network not connected
08-20 14:00:18.580: I/SecureClock(11096): network state changed
08-20 14:00:18.580: I/SecureClock(11096): Network not connected
08-20 14:00:28.530: I/JNI(11096): Trying to load libJNISecureClock.so
08-20 14:00:28.530: D/dalvikvm(11096): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.sonyericsson.secureclockservice/lib/libJNISecureClock.so 0x4051ae00
08-20 14:00:28.550: D/dalvikvm(11096): Added shared lib /data/data/com.sonyericsson.secureclockservice/lib/libJNISecureClock.so 0x4051ae00
08-20 14:00:28.550: D/dalvikvm(11096): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.sonyericsson.secureclockservice/lib/libJNISecureClock.so 0x4051ae00, skipping init
08-20 14:00:28.550: I/SecureClock(11096): Setting up timer
08-20 14:00:28.550: I/SecureClock(11096): Delay=120000
08-20 14:00:28.550: I/SecureClock(11096): Period=43200000
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the file that exhibited the problem?

Comment: @vinaykumar  Hey I am facing similar issue in MuPdf reader. Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

A bug has been opened for this at:

http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693288

and progress can be tracked there. However, no progress will be made without a specimen file to reproduce the problem.....